# Is it possible to create multiple jar files of same project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a maven project which has 12 classes and all the classes have dependency on conf file which is included in the project. I want to create multiple jars of the same project. Let say I want to create separate jar for each classes so that my testing will be easier.Also, I have a main class which runs the entire project.
Could it be possible to do so??
Thanks in advance

I tried extracting the jar but I am able to do for the entire project and not for a particular class.

This my main class which runs the entire project

```
package dicom_ibe;

public class DicomManager 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        DicomOrchestrator dcm = new DicomOrchestrator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn Apache Ant, this build system allows creation of jars in two lines of XML.

Comment: What exactly do you think will be easier to test with multiple jars?

Comment: Actually  I am running the jar as window service so want to create different jar for each class or just want to segregate the project based on functionality. Could this be possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create jars for different classes. Create new project with only main class. Add all created jar files as dependencies. This is will resolve you issue i guess.

What i did is..

1) Created test project which is having Main, HelloWorld, HelloIndia classes. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb3jk.png)

2) Then from eclipse -> right click on each class file and EXPORT -> jar, only for HELLOWORLD and HELLOINDIA class files, not for MAIN class

3) Created new project with MAIN class and added dependecies helloworld and helloindia jars to this new project and export this project as RUNNABLE JAR.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miXfp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO373.png)

As per your question this process will create individual jars for all class files and final MAIN class jar will have all other jars as dependency. Hope this solution will help you.

Thanks..

Comment: export as JAR will work on individual class files to generate as jar.
export as Runnable JAR will zip all project class files

Comment: is it possible to export it as runnable jar?

Comment: Create a different project with only main class and add all dependencies (which is other class jar files)  then you can create runnable jar.. You cannot create runnable jar for class files which didn't have main method