# How to compile Java files and create two diffrent jars?

Tags: java

I have to create two separate .jar files for my project. One is classes.jar where some classes are declared and the second one, main.jar where classes are used. I've already compiled the classes.jar file, but when I try to compile main.java with javac I get "package does not exist" and "cannot find symbol" errors. What can I do to compile the file? How to properly link those .class/.jar files for the compiler to see?

I've tried using `javac -cp bin/classes.jar src/library/Main.java` command.

Comment: Just add `classes.jar` into the classpath when compiling the "main" classes.

Comment: I've already tried that, probably wrongly, using javac -cp bin/classes.jar src/library/Main.java command

Comment: At this point it would really, really help to see a [mcve]. We simply don't have enough information at the moment. (Note that for the minimal example, you should only need two Java classes - one to put in classes.jar and the other to use it.)

Comment: Try adapting the answer from [Is it possible to create multiple jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372851/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-jar-files-of-same-project).

Comment: usually, having two different jars comes from having two different projects

Comment: I solved the problem by moving the main.java to the directory from where it could access .class files. Thanks for your help.